# "Error in service module" problem when logging in remotely (via VMware 7.1) to rhel 8.7 VM

Tags: rhel

I have a RHEL 8.7 VM on VMware 7.1. Every time I try to log in to the server, be it remotely or locally, I cannot do so. If I try to log in remotely (via ssh), the server severs the connection. If I try to log in via the VMware remote console, the host accepts my username and password, but then it spits out "Error in service module" and sends me back to the login prompt. Has anyone seen thie activity before and were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.